# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Counting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Hay
Im working on a project for my exam in C# and ASP.NET Core 6.0 , the teachers want me to count every sign up on a tournament.

*(little more information; Its a tournement website and the database has 2 tables for this. Tournament and Sign Ups. So they want me to count every sign up in the table Sign Ups with the same TournamentID.)*

I dont know how to do this, well i know that i need to use a Count method.

My toughts:

Count list where _context.Tournament.TournamentID == _context.SignUps.TournamentID

I dont know how to put this in a code. Can someone help me?

**Edit 1:

Btw, this is a code i tried, but it dont work.

```
var count = _context.Signups.Count(t => t.TournamentId == id);
            ViewBag.CountingSingups = count;
```

Comment: Group by tournament id, count.

Comment: What are you using to access the db from your application?

Comment: @FrancescoD.M. You mean the connectionstring? Its in the appsettings;
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.; Database=MBONewDB; User Id=SA; Password=MyPassword123#; Trusted_Connection=false; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

Comment: Not what I meant no :) Are you using Entity Framework or something else?

Comment: Ahh I use Entity Framework, Sorry :S

Comment: Btw i got now something like 

var count = _context.SignUps.Count(t => t.TournamentId == _context.Tournaments); 


But that is not working

Comment: Do you want the count for one tournament or for all at once?

Comment: You are giving an TournamentId and want to count tournaments with this id, or you want to have all tournaments ids and its count?

Comment: @Ralf For one tournament

Comment: @adrianMoskal I want to count the sing ups per tournamentID

Comment: Hmm this code seems ok. Try to check while debugging if you have any signups in _context.Signups, do you have any? Or are you sure that given id is correct and equals to any TournamentId in database?

Comment: I just put down a breakpoint at that code. But it doesnt even stop there. So i think the website is not reaching the code

Comment: And yea the Id's are the same

Comment: @Damian yeah so if breakdown doesn't reaching that code there is a problem in code before :/ so this linq query seems ok to me

Answer (score 0):

By following this condition you will get count of Signups for each tournament individually.

```
var count = _context.Signups.GroupBy(gp => gp.TournamentID ).Select(y => new
                {
                    TournamentID = y.Key,
                    CoutOfusers=y.Count()
                 }).ToList();
```